# How to plot the graph using MATLAB (or not matlab))?

Tags: function, matlab, plot, graph, ode

I've got the function fi(ϕ)=γi+sin(2⋅sinϕ) for i=1,2 where γ1=0.01 and γ2=0.02

ϕ1(0)=0.1 and ϕ2(0)=0.2

ϕ1/dt=f1(ϕ)+d⋅sin(ϕ2−ϕ1)

ϕ2/dt=f2(ϕ)+d⋅sin(ϕ1−ϕ2)

where d=0.1

So there should be something like for example this table:

```
t     | ϕ1  | ϕ2
0.00  | 0.1 |0.2
0.01  | ... |...
0.02  | ... |...
...
100.00| ... | ...
```

And so using the received values it's needed to plot a graph by the coordinates

So the question is how to plot the function ϕ2(ϕ1) on the the following graph using MATLAB?
[image]

Comment: Please indicate the cross-post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4341037/how-to-plot-the-graph-using-matlab. Please explain the last two equations in your own words, especially what the variables are (independent, dependent, that is, functions,...) . Alternatively provide some context for these equations.

Comment: @LutzLehmann  thank you! So now I'll  try. Actually it's a system of two equations. and in function `f(ϕ)`  `ϕ` is probably  `ϕ1-ϕ2` (or `ϕ2-ϕ1`). It's not stated, it's only my assumption (maybe I'm not right). And I needed to plot a graph that will show the dependence of `ϕ2` on `ϕ1`. So I probably need to use `ode45` or something to calculate `ϕi/dt` to get ϕi and plot this dependence. also it says that `∆t=0.01` , `Tmax=100`.

Comment: @LutzLehmann or probably I need to use `f1(ϕ1(ϕ2))` and 'f2(ϕ2)'  instead of `f1,2(ϕ)` as it was suggested in the question you've mentioned. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the story of the system might be that you start with two uncoupled and slightly different equations

```
ϕ1/dt=f1(ϕ1)
ϕ2/dt=f2(ϕ2)
```

and connect them with a coupling or exchange term `sin(ϕ2-ϕ1)`,

```
ϕ1/dt=f1(ϕ1)+d⋅sin(ϕ2−ϕ1)
ϕ2/dt=f2(ϕ2)+d⋅sin(ϕ1−ϕ2)
```

In a matlab script you would implement this as

```
y0 = [ 0.1; 0.2 ];
[T,Y] = ode45(eqn,[0, 100], y0);

plot(Y(:,1),Y(:,2));

function dy_dt = eqn(t,y)
  d = 0.1;
  g = [ 0.01; 0.02 ];
  f = g+sin(2*sin(y));
  exch = d*sin(y(2)-y(1));
  dy_dt = f+[d;-d];
end%function
```

which gives almost a diagonal line ending at `[pi; pi]`. With a stronger coupling constant `d` this becomes slightly more interesting.

You can give the parameters as parameter arguments, then you have to declare them via `odeset` in an options object, or use anonymous functions to bind the parameters in the solver call.

Comment: thank you very much!!! you've really helped me a lot! 
May I ask you one more question? I run it in matlab and by changing parameter `b`, the trajectory changes but always returns to the point [pi, pi]. Why does this happens?

Comment: With `d=0.8` I got an arc down ending at about [3.6,-3.6].

Comment: ok that's alright now! thanks one more time!